# Regexp in a matching column sql

Tags: sql, regex, join, sap-iq

I have 2 tables. One of them having one of the columns as regexp's. I want to join the two tables on the regexp column. Cannot seem to be able to do this.
To elaborate: table 1 is (errortype, action, error message) and table 2 is(regexp for error message of each type, error code) join columns are error message and regexp, both string. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
Select * from table1 
left outer join table2 on table1.error_message=table2.regExp.
```

Issue : `table2.regExp` has actual regular expressions that should match one or more `table1.error_messages`. the `=` does not work here.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: New users should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and in your case, I suggest also reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you should [edit] your question according to the information in the above links. So regarding your question: Do you want to see which rows in table 1's _error message_ column are matched by the regexp in table 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` operator. `=` performs exact matches, not pattern matching.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.error_message REGEXP table2.regexp
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, in that case when I am storing the data in table2, the regexp, should I be inserting it with ' (quotes), because REGEXP would need the second string to be in quotes?

Comment: Yes, just like any other string.